# Exception in showing a webform page on iframe of MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I need to show an aspx page content(which holds a asp:chart control) on an iframe of my MVC application view(I am using Razor view engine).

My iframe src is correct as it is hitting Page_Load() of the aspx page.

The web form page is in root of my MVC application. The webform page is executing properly without throwing any  exception.

But, it's not loading the iframe (in MVC app View) & ends up with logging an exception as:

```
 Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
```

Can someone say the reason or the work around to fix it.

Comment: What's the inner exception?

Comment: If you hit the .aspx directly everything works fine?

Comment: yes! It renders the expected result as well. But, something goes wrong while feeling the iframe.

Comment: Is there an inner exception? What is it?